# How to get document.title of homepage from sub url using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need use javascript to get title of website homepage when I browse a sub url of that web site.

if I'm in this url (https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2022/04/02/russia-ukraine-war-news-putin-live-updates/)
the `document.title` will be "Russia-Ukraine war news: Live updates - The Washington Post"
but I need to get "The Washington Post: Breaking News, World, US, DC News and Analysis"
which it `document.title` of this url (https://www.washingtonpost.com) ?

Comment: If you're on that site how are you going to use this JavaScript? User script? Web extension?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var doc = document;
if(window.location.pathname != "/"){
  var data = await fetch(window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/')
  var body = await data.text()
  doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(body,"text/html");
}
console.log(doc.title);
```

Comment: code worked fin in browser but, 
when I used it in Winautomation programe, it is give me an error
"Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules"

Comment: You need to wrap it inside an async method. Instead of `function(){...}` it needs to be `async function(){...}`

Comment: I add `async function(){...}` , but when I run it through Winautomation it give me two error
1- Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
2- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: The 2nd error is caused by the 1st. The 1st error is because you are trying to send request to a site which does not allow that. Problem is that probably you can't disable the CORS feature in the browser. You could try using a CORS proxy server for the request.